# python $test || echo "Test $test failed" && exit 1 not working as expected

Tags: bash

So I have a bash script like the following

```
for test in Test*.py; do
  python $test && python3 $test || echo "Test $test failed" && exit 1
done
echo "All tests pass!"
```

It seems as though even when tests succeed `exit 1` is getting called.

I thought that `&&` had higher precedence than `||` (result of quick Google search [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/opprecedence.html))?

To test this I tried

```
for test in Test*.py; do
  python $test && python3 $test || { echo "Test $test failed" && exit 1 }
done
echo "All tests pass!"
```

But then I got

> ./test: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `done' ./test: line
>   4:`done'

Eventually I got what I expected with

```
for t in Test*.py; do
  python $t && python3 $t || eval 'echo "Test for $t failed" && exit 1'
done
echo "All tests pass!"
```

But this seems less elegant, because I have to fit half of the line in a quoted string.

My question is, why are the first two above snippets not working? Does the operator precedence rules not work as I expect? Also, if `{` and `}` don't work, is there a way of grouping commands without invoking a subshell?

Comment: Have you tried parentheses rather than braces? `python $test && python3 $test || ( echo "Test $test failed" && exit 1 )`

Comment: @weirdev If I use parenthesis, `exit` has no effect, and the script keeps on going. I want the script to die when it hits `exit`.

Comment: The link you provided seems to recommend brackets for separating operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the initial problem, "[[t]he exit status is carried through from whichever command was most recently executed, and skipping a command doesn't change it.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements)" Alternatively, **a skipped command has no return code.** So in a statement like `1 && 2 || 3 && 4`, `4` will run if `3` succeeds *or* if `1 && 2` succeeds (and `3` is therefore skipped).

Also, you need to **add a terminator (`&&`, `||` or `;`) to *each* command in a [grouping](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Command_grouping)**, like so:

```
python $test && python3 $test || { echo "Test $test failed" && exit 1; }
```

Comment: Cool thank you! That did the trick. I'll accept your answer when SO will let me. However, if it's not too much trouble, could you also explain why the script didn't seem to respect precedence rules?

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote your answer again. Your explanation is great, but the reference you link seems like it could be a gem.

Comment: Thanks! That whole web site is a gem, and I wholeheartedly recommend reading every article there if you want to understand Bash at a practical level. It's also a great resource to figure out just what kind of problems Bash is terrible for.

Comment: I'm not sure "a skipped command has no return code" is a useful description; rather, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, which you wouldn't expect coming from nearly any other programming language. `1 && 2 || 3 && 4` is the same as `((1 && 2) || 3) && 4`, not `(1 && 2) || (3 && 4)`.